# Saving comment on iPhone XR under iOS 12.2 gives blank screen

Tags: bug, ios-app

I recently started using the iOS app on an iPhone XR under iOS 12.2 and am finding that it gives a blank screen whenever I save a comment on any post on any Stack Exchange site.

I am able to use the back button to see that the comment has been saved, but is this a bug that can be reproduced and fixed?

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone XR
- OS Version: Version 12.2 (Build 16E227)

Comment: Also on [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359318/3648282).